# Object dependencies and relationships in SQL tables - Best free software to visualization

Tags: untagged

Good morning.

Besides the Microsoft SQL Server Management Studio, what software, preferably free, do you advise to use, that may show better results than the MSQLSMS when viewing object dependencies ou table relationships?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you're a DBA, one of the most beneficial tools I've ever purchased is Red Gate's [SQL Toolbelt](http://www.red-gate.com/products/sql_professional_toolbelt/index.htm).  Specifically what you're looking for is their [SQL Dependency Tracker](http://www.red-gate.com/products/SQL_Dependency_Tracker/index.htm) which is part of the toolbelt or you can purchase it by itself.

I don't work for Red Gate.  Just a happy customer.

Comment: I concur with GregD's answer.

Comment: And about some free tool? Know anyone?

Comment: If free is part of your criteria, it would have been helpful to have that in your original question...

Comment: Sorry for that GregD, now it's more elucidative.